# Cypress typescript module can't recognise a module

Tags: typescript, testing, module, cypress, pageobjects

I'm trying to implement a page object pattern in a project that i cloned. The problem is that when i try to import a module, I get an error from VScode ='File '../path/module' is not a module.' I added module.exports in the module file and I changed 'module' to 'ES2015' in the tsconfig.json. I found a tip that I also should change 'type' of a 'script' for 'module' in the index.html file but the problem is that there is no such file in my project.  Help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found a component-index.html file, I added script tag with attribute type="module", did't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the path from which you're trying to import is correct? Check the parents hierarchy